# multiply 3 strings arrays python

Tags: python, cartesian-product

- a= ['M', 'K', 'J']
- b= ['B', 'C', 'D', 'T','A']
- d= ['A','B','C','Z']
- 
- I want to multiply 3 arrays
- 
- 
- 
- first output would be:
- 
- MBA
- MCA
- MDA
- MTA
- MAA

Comment: Have you try itertools.product ?

Comment: Hi. Have a look at python's standard module itertools, and function [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: Hey and welcome to the stack! Please format your code as code and show your own effort first. Read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to combine [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) and [`''.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) with [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
from itertools import product

out = list(map(''.join, product(a,b,d)))
```

Output:

```
['MBA', 'MBB', 'MBC', 'MBZ', 'MCA', 'MCB', 'MCC', 'MCZ', 'MDA', 'MDB', 'MDC', 'MDZ', 'MTA', 'MTB', 'MTC', 'MTZ', 'MAA', 'MAB', 'MAC', 'MAZ', 'KBA', 'KBB', 'KBC', 'KBZ', 'KCA', 'KCB', 'KCC', 'KCZ', 'KDA', 'KDB', 'KDC', 'KDZ', 'KTA', 'KTB', 'KTC', 'KTZ', 'KAA', 'KAB', 'KAC', 'KAZ', 'JBA', 'JBB', 'JBC', 'JBZ', 'JCA', 'JCB', 'JCC', 'JCZ', 'JDA', 'JDB', 'JDC', 'JDZ', 'JTA', 'JTB', 'JTC', 'JTZ', 'JAA', 'JAB', 'JAC', 'JAZ']
```